# Getting indirect routes in neo4j considering the order in which they appear in a route

Tags: graph, neo4j, shortest-path

So I am trying to get indirect routes in my neo4j graph consisting of stop and route nodes.

Here's my ER diagram of my relational database.

[image]

My model consists of stop nodes with node having name of each stop (The blue coloured nodes in the picture).

I have multiple routes which have the relationship(STOPS_AT) with the stop nodes. These relationship points to the various stops that a bus will make when it's following a particular route.

The Stops at relationship has the following properties.

fare_bt_stops - It has the fare of trip between this stop and the previous stop.
order - Order in which bus stops at stop. Origin being 0

This is how my STOPS_AT relation looks like.

[image]

[image]

So to get the shortest distance between A to C I'm running this query to get the route between A and C.

```
MATCH (a:Stop {name:'A'}), (d:Stop {name:'C'})
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a)-[:STOPS_AT*..12]-(d))
RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x:Stop THEN 'Stop ' + x.name
                                    WHEN x:Route THEN 'Route ' + x.name
                                    ELSE '' END) AS itinerary
```

Which gives output `[Stop 12, Route 4, Stop 13, Route 5, Stop 14]`

But how do I query this model to get the path with the least fare. I have seen other examples for it but in those examples the nodes were directly connected whereas in mine they are connected via Route nodes.

Plus how do I validate the routes according to the stop_order property for example Route `A to B` stops at A first and then on B while Route `C to B` stops at C first and then B so there should not be any way to reach from A to C but this query is not handling this particular case as well. So right now I am handling that in my code which I think is not the best way to do it.

I am stuck on this for the past two days so would appreciate any help that I can get.

Comment: You should describe your model in the question, rather than linking to a GrapheneDB instance (which doesn't seem to exist anymore). That way it remains useful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you're relying too much on the tabular modeling from your relational db. You're working with Neo4j, so you're going to have to consider the best way to transform your tabular model to something that models well and allows rich queries in a graphical model. In this kind of transformation, much of the plumbing from your relational db won't be needed, and that can be hard to recognize and see at the start.

One way you may want to remodel this is by removing your intermediate nodes and instead simply using relationships between each of your stops

So for example, if we classify a route as a path of :Route relationships with the same number, you can create your route fairly easily. It may model something like this:

```
(:Bus{ID:1, color:"green", number:"5"})-[:AssignedTo]->(:BusRoute{number:1}, departureTime:xxx})-[:Start]->(:Stop{name:"a"})-[:Route{number:1, fare:"10", duration:"20"]->(:Stop{name:"b"})-[:Route{number:1, fare:"20", duration:"30", finalStop:true}]->(:Stop{name:"d"})

(:Bus{ID:2, color:"red", number:"7"})-[:AssignedTo]->(:BusRoute{number:2}, departureTime:xxx})-[:Start]->(:Stop{name:"d"})-[:Route{number:2, fare:"10", duration:"20"]->(:Stop{name:"c"})-[:Route{number:2 fare:"20", duration:"30"}]->(:Stop{name:"b"}) ...
```

This makes your routes clear and distinct. Also note that the :Bus assigned to the route is clear, and easily changeable, as the association of a bus to a route is in one place.

Finding the route for route 1, for example would use a query like:

```
MATCH (bus:Bus)-[:AssignedTo]->(busRoute:BusRoute)-[:Start]->(first:Stop)
WHERE busRoute.number = 1
WITH bus, busRoute, first
MATCH (first)-[r:Route*]->(:Stop)
WHERE ALL(route in r | route.number = br.number)
AND LAST(r).finalStop = true
RETURN bus, busRoute, NODES(r) as stops
```

And for a query for shortest path from any stop to any other stop, with the fare as weight, you can either do this yourself with Cypher, or you can use the APOC Procedure call to do this for you.

First, the easy way. If you install the [APOC Procedures library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/tag/3.0.4.1), you can make this query:

```
MATCH (here:Stop), (destination:Stop)
WHERE here.name = xxx AND destination.name = xxx
WITH here, destination
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(here, destination, 'Route>', 'fare') YIELD path, weight
RETURN RELS(path) as rides, weight as cost
```

If you want to do it yourself, you can do it like this (adding a sane limit to your variable path depth)

```
MATCH (here:Stop), (destination:Stop)
WHERE here.name = xxx AND destination.name = xxx
WITH here, destination
MATCH (here)-[rides:Route*..12]->(destination)
WITH rides, REDUCE(cost = 0, ride in rides | cost + ride.fare) AS cost
ORDER BY cost ASC LIMIT 1
RETURN rides, cost
```

Comment: I love you. Seriously I knew there was a better way to do it but was unable to find one as I was thinking in a more relational way of doing things. Your solution makes so much sense you have no idea. I'll try to design one now and I'll get back to you with the results. Thanks you so much :)

Comment: Glad to help! There are a couple hurdles when changing your thinking from relational to graph, it's all part of the process. You also tend to have more freedom in how to model things in your graph, so different primary use cases may require some changes to the model. Hope it works for you, and happy to help if you run into any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information on the model in the question to answer the fare part.

Regarding the order question, if the `Route` has a direction, so should its relationships with the `Stops`:

```
(c:Stop {name: 'C'})-[:STOPS_AT]->(c_to_b:Route)-[:STOPS_AT]->(b:Stop {name: 'B'})
```

Except the relationship type makes no sense now, and you could instead use 2 different types:

```
(c:Stop {name: 'C'})-[:IS_ORIGIN]->(c_to_b:Route)-[:IS_DESTINATION]->(b:Stop {name: 'B'})
```

And now if you follow both types in the same direction, you follow the actual route (if it exists):

```
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a)-[:IS_ORIGIN|IS_DESTINATION*..12]->(d))
```

Comment: Hey there, I'm sorry I didn't really follow what you are trying to say. Can you please elaborate on your answer. Should I model it differently? I am still confused how to share stops between two routes and I could only think of my present model. As you can go from A to B using multiple routes should I create a direct edge between A to B with the edge having an array of routes which serve between these two stops? I have also added my relational er diagram.